# Converting GoogleSheets4 Column to R Date Format

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to convert "CR_bacteria$Date" to a date format. I'm finding trouble in that printing the value returns as:

```
CR_bacteria$Date

[[1]]
[1] "2022-12-28 09:55:00 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2022-12-12 10:56:00 UTC"
```

However, the actual Date is returned as a number. Ex: Row 1 = 1672221300.

I have tried the following, only producing NA values.

```
print(strptime(CR_bacteria$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:", tz = "UTC"))
```

```
test<- CR_bacteria[['Date']] <- strptime(CR_bacteria[['Date']], 
                                 format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:")
```

I have also tried "as.date" with the same result.

Open to any packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lubridate to convert the time/date to just date:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "2022-12-28 09:55:00 UTC"
x_date <- as.Date(ymd_hms(x))
str(x_date)
Date[1:1], format: "2022-12-28"
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. I've returned the error: "unexpected symbol in "str(x_date) Date"". Wouldn't need to link it to the data frame CR_bacteria and apply it to the whole column?